# Windows 10 laptop doesn't charge on a dock

Tags: windows-10, laptop, docking-station

I have a HP zBook 17 running Windows 10. When I remove it and return it to the dock, it does not recognize that it's connected to power and able to charge. The dock has a sticker that says "Pumba 1.0". Searching for that turns up an [identical looking model](https://www.cdw.com/product/HP-230-W-Docking-Station/2754683).

If the laptop is on the dock and I plug the AC adapter into the laptop **without** plugging it into the wall, it immediately begins charging from the dock, and continues charging when the AC adapter is removed. I assume there's a microswitch inside the power connector that it should ignore when it's on the dock, but it's refusing to charge until that switch is pressed.

Is this likely to be a firmware bug, or could it be related to some setting that I can access?

Comment: The OS should not be effecting this. If the OS controlled when the laptop charged or not then the laptop would never charge when it was turned off.

Comment: Please include the make and model of both your laptop and the docking station. This could be important as there might be firmware or patch releases from the vendor that could resolve this issue.

Comment: @EBGreen Good point.

Comment: @MichaelFrank Edited.